# Script to copy variable into xml file

Tags: xml, loops, powershell, csv

I have some software that parses an .xml file for login information (username and password). In the past, we've been using the same username and password for hundreds of users for this software and it has become a security concern. I can easily replace this .xml file with new login information but I need a little help getting the usernames into place for hundreds of users.

So far I have generated an XML file for each computer that needs to be copied to.

For example:

```
Computer1.xml
Computer2.xml
Computer3.xml
...
Computer290.xml
```

The XML file itself goes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
 <server default="true">
  <connection ssl="false">
   <address>fax.servername.com</address>
   <login>USERNAME</login>
   <password>PASSWORD</password>
  </connection>
  <about>
   <model>MODELNUMBER</model>
   <version>VERSIONNUMBER</version>
  </about>
  <user>
   <contact_url>http://contacturl/users/username</contact_url>
   <username>USERNAME</username>
   <name>JOHN DOE</name>
   <organization>Company Name</organization>
   <default_cover_page_enabled>false</default_cover_page_enabled>
   <default_cover_page_name></default_cover_page_name>
   <priority>3</priority>
   <max_attempts>3</max_attempts>
   <interval>300</interval>
   <receipt>failure</receipt>
   <receipt_attachment>pdf</receipt_attachment>
  </user>
 </server>
</settings>
```

I get that storing a password in plain text is a terrible idea, but unfortunately the software is old and doesn't support another method.

I have a csv file that contains usernames and which computer they use.

e.g.
(Edit: changed to CSV file format)

> ```
> User1,Computer1
> User2,Computer2
> User3,Computer3
> ```

How can I take those usernames and pop those into the xml files so that they correspond to the correct computer name?

Comment: Just FYI, your sample is not csv (comma-separated values). :)

Comment: Your XML files are supposedly already named after the computers. Why would you need to insert the computer names from the CSV? Also, what does your XML structure look like? If the files contained just the snippet you posted they wouldn't be valid XML. And what should the resulting XML look like? If you're not posting any code, at least be clear about what you have, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ansgar -- good questions. I don't need to insert the computer name into the XML, I just need to make sure the username is paired to the right computername.xml file. Basically we have 290 users with different computer names, so I need to make sure the username matches up with the computer name. I updated the XML code so you can see the whole context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider this user-computer.csv:

```
UserName,ComputerName
User1,Computer1
User2,Computer2
User3,Computer3
```

Then you could try the following (modify with correct proper paths, using current directory in this demo):

```
Import-Csv -Path .\user-computer.csv | ForEach-Object {
    #$_ is the current object

    #Your "xml" is not a valid xml file as it doesn't have a root element, so we should use text replacement to modify the files.

    (Get-Content -Path ".\$($_.ComputerName).xml") -replace '(?<=<username>)(.*?)(?=<\/username>)', $_.UserName | Set-Content -Path ".\$($_.ComputerName).xml"
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!!! Just another small question to ask about that particular command... what if I had more than just 2 fields in the CSV like

`UserName,Password,URL,ComputerName`

Is it possible to run the -replace multiple times and point it to $_.Password next and then $_.URL?

Comment: Yes. You could run `.. -replace 'pattern1', 'newvalue1 -replace 'pattern2', 'newvalue2'`. If the values are on the same line as ex. `<username>`, then you could also create one pattern that modifies multiple parts in the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate the computer/user pairing against the list in the CSV I'd create a hashtable from the CSV:

```
$csv = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | % {
  $csv[$_.ComputerName] = $_.UserName.Trim()
}
```

and then do the validation like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\to\*.xml' | % {
  [xml]$xml = Get-Content $_.FullName
  $username = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//username').'#text'.Trim()
  if ($username -ne $csv[$_.BaseName]) {
    "[{0}] User mismatch: {1}, {2}" -f $_.BaseName, $username, $csv[$_.BaseName]
  }
}
```